# Java Socket can not send system.lineseparator

Tags: java, sockets

I have been developing a p2p chat server system. It works well no problem when chatting. But I want to send file also. What I have done is that I have read the file from sender side and copy that in string and then send the string to receiver. Then on the receiver side the string will be written on a file on receiver PC. Problem is the string is not accepting lineseparator means it is not sending whole file rather only first line. Let me give an example :

```
   String st = "I have done 
                this " ;
```

when I send this string it only sends this part "I have done ". Now I am sharing the code.This is message Transmitter side :

```
 public class MessageTransmitter extends Thread {

String message, hostname, user;
int targetport, receivePort, key, trigger;

public MessageTransmitter() {
}

public MessageTransmitter(String message, String hostname, int targetport, int receivePort, String user, int key, int trigger) {
    this.message = message;
    this.hostname = hostname;
    this.targetport = targetport;
    this.user = user;
    this.receivePort = receivePort;
    this.key = key;
    this.trigger = trigger;

}

@Override
public void run() {

    if (trigger == 1) {

        String filePath = message;

        String[] tokens = filePath.split("[\\\\|/]");
        String filename = tokens[tokens.length - 1];





        try {
            // FileReader reads text files in the default encoding.
            FileReader fileReader
                    = new FileReader(filePath);

            // Always wrap FileReader in BufferedReader.
            BufferedReader bufferedReader
                    = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

            try {
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

                    line2 += line;
                    line2 += System.lineSeparator();
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MessageTransmitter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

            try {
                // Always close files.
                bufferedReader.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MessageTransmitter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("Unable to open file '"
                    + filePath + "'");
        }


        try {
            Socket s1 = new Socket(hostname, targetport);
            s1.getOutputStream().write(line2.getBytes());
            s1.close();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MessageTransmitter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }



    }
```

This is receiver side :

```
   public class MessageListener extends Thread {

ServerSocket server;
int port, key, trigger;
WritableGUI gui;
String fileData;

public MessageListener(WritableGUI gui, int port, int key) {
    this.port = port;
    this.gui = gui;
    this.key = key;
    try {
        server = new ServerSocket(port);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MessageListener.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

public MessageListener() {
    try {
        server = new ServerSocket(port);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MessageListener.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

@Override
public void run() {

    Socket clientSocket;

    try {
        while ((clientSocket = server.accept()) != null) {
            InputStream is = clientSocket.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            String line = br.readLine();
            if (line != null) {
    gui.write(line);
} catch (IOException ex) {

         Logger.getLogger(MessageListener.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
```

Comment: I don't think this even compiles. I dont see where `line2` is declared in your first class for example. Please read and follow [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly.

Comment: By the way, in case `line2` is a `String`, you should be aware that it's inefficient to append to a String in a loop. Use `StringBuilder` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a fundamental flaw in your logic: it isn't the **sender** that has to insert line breaks. That is something that the client that wants to *write* the file to disk should do.

What if your sender is using Linux, and the client is running windows? Then your solution would use Linux newlines on a Windows system. Can't work. Well, it does work, but the results will not be to your liking.

In that sense: you could for example send the file line by line (and then have the receiver read those and add new lines).

Alternatively: your sender could insert some kind of *place holder* (say `"$$$NEWLINE$$$` into the string that is sent over. And then the client replaces all occurrences of this place holder with *its* newline character.

And finally: please read about using StringBuilder, instead of going for the + operator.

Comment: well how can I understand where to put lineseparator in a big file ? Let's say my file includes these lines :


           I am a boy.
           I go to school. 
           My school is big .

How can I understand on receiver side where to put lineseparator ?

Comment: See my updates. And again: which part of "sent the file line by line" is giving you trouble? You got two people giving you the same advise already. Maybe you first digest this input, before coming back with more questions.

Comment: It's quite common for the line separator "place holder" to be either "\n" or "\r\n" (for example, FTP text mode and other protocols) and the receiver sees the "\n" or "\r\n" and translates it to its own environment's line separator. Also I don't see the logic of sending line-by-line without any line separator. If you send an extremely long line, some component somewhere along the path from sender to receiver may split it into multiple parts, and then the receiver would erroneously think it's multiple lines.

Comment: Ah thanks to all.. I actually did not understand that continuous transmission would be done. I did it. Thanks for your helps.

Answer (score 1):

You should send a line at a time, rather than trying to read the entire file into memory. The receiver should read a line at a time, and append the local system's line separator character before writing each line to the file.

```
String st = "I have done 
            this " ;
```

I don't know what this is, but it isn't Java.

Comment: He got that answer 13 minutes ago already and it didn't help him ;-)

Comment: @GhostCat Helped him this time though :-|

Comment: True enough ;-)